# MongoDB fetching data from 2 seperate collections using 1 ID

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have 2 collections one is speakers:

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"_class" : "Speaker",
"name" : "Assar",
"bio" : "I like cars"
}
```

and the other one is a session where the speaker attends:

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"_class" : "Session",
"startDate" :"2015-10-01",
"endDate" : "2015-10-15",
"subject" : "Studies",
"description" : "Fun",
"speakers" : [ 
    "1"
],
}
```

I am trying to create a view in which I could have speakers data with the session he/she is giving. How can I get the data of the session when I only have the ID of the speaker and in the session->speakers the speakers element is an array?

I am really new to noSQL DBs so maybe some kind of advice. I've googled around and read something about MapReduce, but haven't still figured out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data of the session when you only have the ID of the speaker, use the following query:

```
var speakerId = 1;
db.session.find({"speakers": speakerId})
```

This will return all the session documents where the `speakers` array has an element with value 1.